# Do mobile phones automatically connect to spoofed cellular tower antenna?

Tags: encryption, mobile, gsm, cellular

I was told that an attacker is able to create a fake cellular tower antenna imitator near your mobile phone, and your phone will automatically connect to it, whether that antenna has an encrypted connection or not, and thus the attacker can see your transmissions, SMS, etc.. is that correct?

Comment: There is a pretty good writeup / PoC about the whole topic here: https://www.evilsocket.net/2016/03/31/how-to-build-your-own-rogue-gsm-bts-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: Most fake base station simply jammed the signal and push tons of malicious junk SMS, etc than intercepting the user mobile traffics.  OTH, operation such as `Stingray` base station can carry out sophisticated MiTM attack.

Comment: @mootmoot how surprising fact, why not phone-manufacturers or OS creators gave an exlicit warning when using illegal signal, which doesn't comply with Sim-Card's encryption?

Comment: What do you mean by an "illegal signal, which doesn't comply with Sim-Card's encryption"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your phone will not be able to differentiate between a regular and a fake cell tower and will connect to whichever has the strongest signal.

As for the encryption, not really sure what you mean. Since the attacker owns the base station, he can monitor all the traffic going through there. The over-the-air encryption between the phone and the fake base station doesn't really matter here - the only traffic that an attacker cannot see is data that is end-to-end encrypted between the phone and, say, a web service it accesses.

Comment: @schroeder ok, asked here: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/204078/56001